# Clojure: Refs example for bank transaction

Tags: concurrency, clojure, stm, refs

I am still noob at Clojure, right know I am trying to resolve a problem involving bank transaction scenario for university.

The problem is quite easy: I have to develop a solution to **credit, debit and transfer money**.

I stopped here:

```
(def account
    (ref 100))

(defn credit [account amount]
  "Credit"
  (dosync
    (alter account + amount)))


(defn debit [account amount]
  "Debit"
  (dosync
    (if (> amount (balance account))
      (throw (Exception. "Insuficient Funds"))
      (alter account - amount))))

(defn transfer [from to amount]
  "Transfer"
  (dosync
    (if (<= amount (balance from)) 
      (do 
        (Thread/sleep 10)
        (debit from amount)


        (credit to amount))
      (throw
        (Exception. "Insuficient Funds")))))
```

I think its nothing to hard to understand and the code above is working.

I should add the account number, description of the transaction, data and amount and storage in memory in each function above like:

```
 (defn credit [account description data amount]
  "Credit"
  (dosync
    (alter account + amount)))
```

I have tried with hash-map, vectors and other things but didn't work. Also I am trying to find this solution in this book: Clojure Programming O'reilly, but still difficult to implement.

Thank you for your time and let me know if you need more infos.

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: I should add other "parameters" in each function in the way they can work, I have edited my question above, is it clear ?

Comment: Not entirely.  Right now your `credit` function produces a single value.  Do you want it to produce a series of values?  So `(credit account 20)` would produce something like `[120 "deposit" timestamp]`?  Have you tried working with `assoc-in`?  What is `data` supposed to represent?

Comment: Yes, I got it.  Wasn't that hard I just needed a lit bit of more time studying.

Comment: Woot!  If you feel your solution could help others, don't hesitate to answer your own question and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a way to develop this scenario.

When creating an bank account I am using refs and a structure to save all data needed (name account, number account and a operation list with all transactions that will be created)

```
(defn create-account [name account-number]
  "Create account"
  (ref (merge {:name name :account-number account-number :operations '()})))

(def joey 
  "Account for tests"
  (create-account "joey" 12345678))
```